# I want to read data from store for Extjs 4 but it shows [object object]

Tags: javascript, combobox, store, extjs4.2

This is my model:

```
data: i
0: i
data: Object
events: Object
hasListeners: k
id: "region-ext-record-344"
index: 0
internalId: "ext-record-344"
modified: Object
phantom: false
raw: Array[2] // i want to get those two elements one displayField, another valueField
0: "01"
1: "Region 1"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
store: i
stores: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
1: i
2: i
3: i
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I can post the code if you want to!
I tried to read store like:
`store: regionStore`, but it is showing me an empty box with 4 empty lines equal to item count in my store, then I tried to do like `store: regionStore.data.items` and now it shows me `[object object]` lines, I totally get it why, but can't find solution for that. I am new to all ExtJs stuff, I am using ExtJs 4 though.

My model looks like that :
`Ext.regModel('region', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'String'}
       });`
and my store looks like that:
 
`var regionStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        id: 'regionStore',
        model: 'region',
        data: MyDesktop.GridWindow.getRegionData() //that is data from ajax response 
        });`

My combobox:
`{
  xtype: 'combobox',
  value: "region",
  store: regionStore,
  width: 135,
  id: 'regionCombo'
  editable: false
}`

Comment: Not sure what you are specifically asking

Comment: @neelsg well I can't get elements from my store and put it into combobox. so my question is what kind of data should I give to combobox `store` property?

Comment: If you posted the definition of your model, with the field names, it would be more helpful. For future questions do not post the internal representation of the ExtJs object, rather post the definition ( as in Ext.define ).

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Sorry for that that is my first question on Stackoverflow, my model just has two params `id` and `name`, nothing complicated. Check updated question i will post it there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started off correctly, but you didn't specify which fields to use. Add the missing configuration :

```
store: regionStore,
valueField: 'id',
displayField: 'name'
```

For a combobox you can define a store inline as :

```
store: [[1, 'first option'], [2, 'second option']],
```

In this case you will not need to declare the value and the display field. They are implicit.

Comment: I have tried that, many times in many different ways, but it didn't help, my guess is that problem is with json string reader, because parameter is called store, if it can't accept simple store as a data than it is nonsense, that's why I asked what kind of data should I give to store to be valid store, now I am giving js array parsed from JSON string, it is simple numeric array and it works, but when I try with array of objects I fail to take that data and put to combo

Comment: It must take a simple store as parameter. Your object dump shows that your record is ok, but this is not the store

Comment: And what kind of data should I give to store ? **JSON**? or **JS Array**?

Comment: How did you define your store ? An arrayStore takes an array, a jsonStore takes json. For the sake of a combobox you can define a store as double array.

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged your question extjs 4.2, but your code is old style and not following recommendations. I really recommend you to read the manual, especially the introduction to MVC.

Ext.regModel is deprecated as of version 4.0.0. Change your code as follows and save it to the file app/model/Region.js :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Region', {
    extends: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

In file app/store/Regions.js :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Regions', {
    extends: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
    //id: notice that id is no longer necessary
    model: 'Region',
    //data: you load the store from the server, so the data is loaded automatically
    autoLoad: true
})
```

Your combobox becomes:

```
xtype: 'combobox', 
value: 'region',
store: 'Regions', 
width: 135,
id: 'regionCombo',
editable: false,
valueField: 'id',
displayField: 'name'
```

I never used extjs before 4.2, but it seems the changes introduced with version 4 are important. It may be difficult to adopt the new paradigms. But I'm sure it radically simplifies your code. You certainly never will regret this step.
Also with the release of version 5.0, I think it's time to develop new habits and leave ExtJs 2.0 coding style behind.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I haven't worked on Extjs 2.0 though. It's not difficult at all, that is what our profession is all about, to develop our habits and knowledge! I can't vote u cuz I have less rank less than 15 :))